# Error with textplot in wordcloud

Tags: r, graph, word-cloud

I am getting an error when I use the textplot() function in the wordcloud package to label points in a graph (a PCA).

The error is: `Error in match.arg(halign) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector`

Here are the x and y variables:

```
> pca1$li
         Axis1       Axis2
01 -26.3659354  18.0330276
02 -19.3576309 -18.9132485
03 -27.2273522   3.3373583
04 -23.0849100   0.9764428
05   8.1548417  29.4034493
06  14.9676626  -8.4668479
07  -9.2283936   4.5088119
08  17.9377761 -11.3030900
09  -0.8272139   2.3342824
10  30.3111878  18.8577228
11   2.0019239  -6.2150041
12  22.2964319  34.6544348
13  25.4172737 -39.6409997
14   4.4278974  -5.5672158
15   4.2769304 -11.4208116
16  19.2807143  -7.9307193
17   5.1918409  -5.2005851
18 -17.6999115 -26.7897873
19 -15.5909519   6.0809629
20  -3.6095312   1.2653160
21 -12.7500774   8.5864060
22   1.4774272  13.4100946
```

The text (which I here call labels) is supposed to be a character vector, which I made sure of:

```
> labels
 [1] "Vipond Park"     "Little Joe"      "Napa Sunset"     "Deadline"        "Deschutes"       "Gifford Pinchot"
 [7] "Mount Hood"      "Okanogan"        "Warm Springs"    "Colville"        "Wenatchee"       "Olympic"        
[13] "Smithers"        "Mount Stevens"   "Jesmond"         "McBridePeak"     "Cataract"        "Prairie Bluff"  
[19] "Tom Beal"        "Humboldt"        "Warner"          "Goosenest"      

> class(labels)
[1] "character"
```

Here are plotting specifics (I add more info than necessary, because I sometimes plot more data points):

```
> myPch <- c(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18,
+           18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18)
> 
> myCol <- transp(c("blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple","blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple",
+    "blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple", "blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple", "blue","red",
+      "darkgreen","black","purple", "blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple", "blue","red","darkgreen",
+      "black","purple", "blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple","blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple", 
+       "blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple","blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple", "blue","red",
+       "darkgreen","black","purple","blue","red","darkgreen","black","purple"),1)
> 
> 
>
```

I plot the data:

```
> plot(pca1$li, col=myCol, cex=3, pch=myPch)

> abline(h=0,v=0,col="grey",lty=2)
```

I then go to add the labels to the plot, but I get the error below.

```
> textplot(pca1$li[,1], pca1$li[,2], words = labels, cex=1.4, new=FALSE)
Error in match.arg(halign) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is due to incorrect syntax used for textplot function:

```
textplot(object, halign=c("center","left","right"),
     valign=c("center", "top", "bottom"), cex, ... )
```

In your example, the "object" argument is given as pca1$li[,1], while "halign" is given as pca1$li[,2].

Since "halign" only accepts the arguments of "center", "left" or "right", the incorrect argument given pca$li[,2] returns the error message.

Comment: Thank you - you indirectly answered my question.  I was intending to use textplot in the wordcloud package (not in gplots).  Since I had loaded gplots and wordcloud, the formula for wordcloud was not working.  With only the package wordcloud loaded, all is good now!!!